# Dynamic allocation of structs in C

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, struct, allocation

I have a problem with dynamic memory allocation. Here is the code so please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int i;

typedef struct{
  int A;  
}node;


typedef struct Model
        {                            
            node *m;    
        } Model;
        Model M;

void initialize(Model *a, int size)
{
    a->m = (node*) malloc(size);
}


void model_init(Model *a, int len)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<len;i++) a->m[i].A = 20;
}


int main()
{
initialize(&M ,10);
model_init(&M, 10);
for (i=0;i<10;i++) printf("%d\n",M.m[i].A);
}
```

I am trying to make a Model that has 10 nodes and I want to assign values to nodes in variable A. The printf shows (-1819044973, -1819044973, 14128019, 3969, 0, 0, 0 ...)

I just want it to say for example *M.m[2].A=20*

What am I doing wrong? please help.

TY

Comment: Your code has a leak. I don't see a `free()` for the `malloc`

Comment: Why are you declaring main-local variables in the global scope?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
void initialize(Model *a, int size)
{
    a->m = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node) *size); // NOTICE HERE!!!!
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `initialize` function allocates a number of bytes then `model_init` later assumes that many node instances will be available.  `node` is larger than 1 byte (at least sizeof(int) bytes) so you write beyond the end of allocated memory.

The easiest fix is to change `initialize`:

```
void initialize(Model *a, int elements)
{
    a->m = malloc(elements * sizeof(node));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For more information on the fact that you don't have to cast malloc : 
[Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)